# Modify Attributes Individually Using Group Selection

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to modify attributes individually for each element when using group selection, and if so, how can this be done? For example:

```
.inner, .outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  .inner-color: red;
  .outer-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with a preprocessator like sass o stylus
Check this :
http://sass-lang.com/